# Two vertical lines with expressions spanning a few rows between them (math)

Tags: math-mode

I'm pretty new to Latex, learning it while doing. I mainly use doc and latex wiki, but there are occasions when I can't find something.
I am doing some math. I need to have some math formulas followed by vertical lines and formulas spanning some rows between those vertical lines. Something like a notation of variable substitution in integrals. 
My explanation isn't perfect, so I made a picture of what I basically need.
[image: What I need]

Would be thankful for your advices on how I can achieve similar output.

UPD. Made this post hastily. Found the answer myself.

The easiest thing with ordinary latex I had to do was this code:

```
y= \begin{equation} \left \rVert
    \begin{split} a = 2 \\
    b = c \\
    d = g 
    \end{split}
    \right \rVert \end{equation} = gosdfds
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd define my own environment for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\newenvironment{subst}
 {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \left\|\begin{array}{l}}
 {\end{array}\right\|}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\int x\sqrt{x-1}\diff x
\begin{subst}
t=\sqrt{x-1}, t^2=x-1,\\
x=t^2+1, \diff x=2t\diff t
\end{subst}
=\int(t^2+1)\cdot t\cdot 2t\diff t
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The advantage is that you can freely change the definition of `subst` and this will be reflected in all instances thereof.

[image]

Comment: Readability would be enhanced by having a bit more whitespace after the commas in the middle part of this equation, i.e., right before `t^2=` and `\diff x=`.

Comment: @Mico Maybe. In any case I prefer a comma or a semicolon instead of the arrow.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Vmatrix env?

Comment: @daleif It's not a matrix; removing the padding, like `Vmatrix` does, didn't seem right (I tried, of course).

Answer (score 1):

It may be nice for your readers if you state the substitution steps one by one. Using the idea suggested in @egreg's answer to use a dedicated environment -- called `substitutions`, say -- that lists the steps one at a time, one might typeset your equation as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides 'aligned' environment
\newcommand{\dee}{\,\mathrm{d}}

\newenvironment{substitutions}{%
  \quad\left\lVert\begin{aligned}}{%
  \end{aligned}\,\right\rVert\quad}

\begin{document}
\[
\int \!x\sqrt{x-1}\dee x
\begin{substitutions}
t&=\sqrt{x-1}\\
t^2&=x-1\\
x&=t^2+1\\
\dee x&=2t\dee t
\end{substitutions}
=\int(t^2+1)\cdot t\cdot 2t\dee t
=2\int \! t^2(t^2+1)\dee t
\]
\end{document}
```